# Android How to avoid weekend from android default date picker

Tags: android, datepicker, custom-controls

I want to make a custom date picker in Android which will only show weekdays i.e. Monday to Friday, skipping week-end. looking for some help to start with.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this [project](https://www.open-sourced.de/show_article.php?articleid=56).

In this case he only removed Sundays but you can adjust it to remove Saturdays also, like this:

```
  if (choosenDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == 
                    Calendar.SUNDAY || Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == 
                    Calendar.SATURDAY ||
                    now.compareTo(choosenDate) < 0) {
                    dateTextView.setTextColor(
                        Color.parseColor("#ff0000")
                    );
                    ((Button) dialog.getButton(
                    AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE))
                        .setEnabled(false);
                }
```

Hope it helps.

*he just prevented the user from choose them, but I think you can hide it like this inside your if:

```
    dateTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: i tried that link code but it contains error. I am now using date slider and trying to skip week ends.