# disabling day of the week CalendarPickerView?

Tags: java, android

How to disable day of the week example:
have ride calendar where a calendar to mark services.
When riding schedule, sometimes there are days of the week that are not considered.
in case every Monday, Thursday and Sunday of the month.
How do I disable using CalendarPickerView?

obs.: sorry google translate,thank.

```
enter code here
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="webservice.tablayout.teste"
    android:id="@+id/layout">

   <com.squareup.timessquare.CalendarPickerView
        android:id="@+id/calendarPV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="325dp" />
</RelativeLayout>


public class AgendarActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Servico servico;

    private SimpleDateFormat sdFormat;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_agendar);

        Calendar nextYear = Calendar.getInstance();
        nextYear.add(Calendar.YEAR, 7);

        CalendarPickerView calendar = (CalendarPickerView) findViewById(R.id.calendarPV);
        Date today = new Date();

        calendar.init(today, nextYear.getTime()).withSelectedDate(today);
    }
}
```

Comment: This example disables week-ends. You could adjust for your needs : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643493/android-how-to-avoid-weekend-from-android-default-date-picker

Comment: I could not get the idea the link you now, thank you.